# Find all intersections for m timespans of n parties

Tags: algorithm, intervals, timeslots

I just can't figure out a nice way to solve the following problem:

For an event I have n parties (`party_id`) taking part. Each party has m `availabilities` for said event in the form of `start_date` and `end_date`.

What I would like to know is all possible combinations of overlapping `availabilities` containing exactly one `availability` for each `party_id`. I discovered Interval Trees (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) which might be utilized, but as I said I can't quite figure it out.

So thanks for any thoughts on that!

Comment: Just to get it right, what's meant with *all possible combinations etc etc...*. Could you provide an example just for clarity?

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way is sort all your events (`start_date` and `end_date` alike) by time.  Then go through this list in chronological order, while keeping track of all "active" parties (i.e., those which have started, but not stopped).

The above method is a batch process, which should let you find all possible combinations of a given schedule easily.  The *interval tree* you mention is useful in cases where you want to *incrementally update* your set of parties -- the datastructure can make individual queries about a *particular time* much cheaper than re-running the batch process for each update or query.

Comment: Events do not have times. They are available for any timeslot all parties are available at the same time. On second thought, that might be possible for all event availabilities.